# c# set cursor to "Working in Background" cursor

Tags: c#, mouse-cursor

How can I set a form's [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.aspx) to the Working in Background cursor? I know how to set it to the WaitCursor but I can't find the Working in Background (aka Busy Interactive) cursor. I'm using a background worker and figured this would be an easy way to inform the user what's going on.

[image: Working In Background Cursor]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cursor.Current = Cursors.AppStarting;

Comment: What a poorly named cursor but that's what I was looking for. Thanks.